# Динамические ссылки с кириллицей - правильно? [ReactJS]

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Есть интернет-магазин, есть категории "Компьютеры", "Телефоны" и т.д.
**Вопрос**: правильно ли делать динамический роутинг с кириллицей в ссылке?

**Отрывок** кода с динамическим роутом:

```
enum RoutePublicNames {
  CATALOG = "/catalog/:catalogName",
}

const publicRoutes = useRoutes([
    { path: RoutePublicNames.CATALOG, element: <Catalog />}
  ]);
```

Ссылка, которую я получил в браузере:

```
http://localhost:3000/catalog/Компьютеры
```

Ссылка при копировании и вставке(так же рабочая):

```
http://localhost:3000/catalog/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B
```

Всё работает **исправно**, однако в браузере вылезает варнинг:

```
No routes matched location "/catalog/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B"
```

Разумно ли я поступаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В идеальности конечно избавиться от кириллицы в рутере вовсе.

Например заменить её на `/catalog/kompjuteri` или алиас `/catalog/computers`.

Но можно поставить хук на history router.

Вот пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592020

В функциональном программировании это `useLocation`

Дальше просто прогоняешь строку через `(route) => route.pathname = decodeURI(route.pathname)`

Comment: Хм, вот оно как :) 
Спасибо большое! Буду работать.

Отмечу решением, но +1 к полезности не могу добавить - аккаунт новенький совсем.